# Wacom intuos CTH480 ubuntu 12.04

Tags: kernel, software-installation

I got a brand new wacom intuos cth480 the other day, did some research and found out how to get the drivers but when I do `./config` at the end i get this

```
BUILD ENVIRONMENT:
       linux kernel - yes 
      kernel source - no 

We could not find the kernel development environment to build the driver.
Please install the kernel source or the kernel development package and try again.

user@ChrUbuntu:~/Desktop/input-wacom-0.20.0$
```

I really want to get this working I tried installing kernel but nothing worked. If you can please respond very specific on how to get it to work as I'm not 100% familiar with ubuntu Like this? **So this is what you want me to do**

Comment: You should install the `build-essential` package.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running kernel version 3.2 while the makefile is looking for 3.4 sources to build modules.

I recommend installing the [hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) (HWE) instead by installing package `linux-image-generic-lts-saucy`. Note that you also need to install the corresponding xserver stack (like `xserver-xorg-lts-saucy`) to have your system in a supported state.

Comment: I doubt he can since he's using Chrubuntu.

Comment: I saw that, but wasn't sure. If he can't boot another kernel, then he may be out of luck.